# How to calculate this double integral in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, improper-integrals

Good evening, I'm trying to solve an exercise in introductory statistics.

> [image]

After applying the condition that $\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y = 1$, I find that $c = 3/2$.Then $$\mathbb{P}\left(X \leqslant-\frac{1}{2}, Y \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x, y) \,\mathrm{d}y \right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

The solution given in my lecture note is $$=\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{3}{2} d y\right) d x+\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{x^{2}} \frac{3}{2} d y\right) d x$$

I could not figure out how to split in such way. Could you please elaborate on this issue? Thank you so much!

**Update:** Here's the picture of the support, but I still don't know how to use the graph of the support to calculate the integral.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to plot the support region together with the lines $y=\frac12$ and $x=-\frac12$?

Comment: Hi @dfnu, I've attched the picture of the support, but I still don't know how to use the graph of the support to calculate the integral.

Comment: Perfect. Now draw the two straight lines. You'll see in this way the area in which you need to integrate your function. Can you first spot that?

Comment: I will do it myself in a moment, if noone else answers you before

Comment: Thank you so much for all your comment. Honestly, I'm not taught double integral in undergrad. This is the first time I see it in the course in Master. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you understand the integrals limits from here?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness! It's so informative. I got it!